# SoundPool error "erase can not get the lock"

Tags: android, soundpool

As far as I can tell, my app runs fine but I notice this error from the SoundPool being reporting often in the logcat.

```
E/SoundPool(28182): 2 mChannels.erase can not get the lock
```

Any ideas as to what would cause this? I tried removing my thread synchronization code but I am still receiving the error.

This was observed using a Galaxy S2 (SC-02C) running Android 2.3.6.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that I propose for you :

- Create an instance of SoundPool by sound with maxStreams = 1
- Set volume 0 to only one streamID returned by play() method

This solution is not very clean I agree...

---

```
public class Sound {

    public final static int STREAM = AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM;

    private SoundPool pool;
    private int soundID;
    private int streamID;

    public Sound(Context context, int resID) {
        pool = new SoundPool(1, STREAM, 0);
        soundID = pool.load(context, resID, 1);
    }

    public final void play() {
        streamID = pool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    }

    public final void stop() {
        pool.setVolume(streamID, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static Sound alarm1;
    public static Sound alarm2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setVolumeControlStream(Sound.STREAM);
        if(alarm1 == null) alarm1 = new Sound(this, R.raw.alarm1);
        if(alarm2 == null) alarm2 = new Sound(this, R.raw.alarm2);

        findViewById(R.id.play_1).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) { alarm1.play(); }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.stop_1).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) { alarm1.stop(); }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.play_2).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) { alarm2.play(); }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.stop_2).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) { alarm2.stop(); }
        });
    }

}
```

---

And to manage all your sounds, we can imagine a library like this :

---

```
public class Soundlib {

    private Context context;
    private HashMap<Integer, Sound> library;

    public Soundlib(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        library = new HashMap<Integer, Sound>();
    }

    public final void add(int... rawID) {
        for(int id : rawID) library.put(id, new Sound(context, id));
    }

    public final void play(int... rawID) {
        for(int id : rawID) library.get(id).play();
    }

    public final void stop(int... rawID) {
        for(int id : rawID) library.get(id).stop();
    }

    public final void stopAll() {
        for(int id : library.keySet()) stop(id);
    }

}
```

---

```
// to initilize sound library
if(soundlib == null) soundlib = new Soundlib(this){{
    // to add one or more sounds
    add(R.raw.alarm1, R.raw.alarm2);
}};

// to play one or more sounds
soundlib.play(R.raw.alarm1);

// to stop one or more sounds
soundlib.stop(R.raw.alarm1);

// to stop all sounds
soundlib.stopAll();
```

---

Comment: Thanks so much for the work put into the code. I have a requirement to play multiple sounds simultaneously so setting the max streams to 1 is not an option unfortunately. Setting the volume to 0 is an interesting approach that I might adopt but as it stands, the application runs but this error that is being reported has sparked my curiosity as to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error log is caused by the **play()** / **stop()** method of your SoundPool instance.

Do you try to play / stop an audio stream?

Comment: I load about 15 sound resources using the load method of a SoundPool instance. I then use the returned stream ids to play / stop the audio files frequently. Would be nice to avoid errors if possible but is this one unavoidable?

Comment: According to the documentation, **play()** method requires a **soundID** and return a **streamID** and **stop()** method requires the **streamID** returned by **play()** method. In your comment, i understand you play / stop stream with same id (**soundID**). I think your error come from the stop method which wait the play return.

Comment: I apologize, I rechecked my code and I am in fact retaining sound ids from the load method and separately retaining stream ids when playing and using the stream ids to stop the audio. I noticed that this seems to occur when trying to stop audio that is already finished playing but since there is no API for checking play state at API level 7, not sure if there is any way around this.

Comment: Do you want to play sounds one by one? In this case, you can add a blank sound to your sound pool, set maxStream to 1 and play blank sound to stop. In the other case, MediaPlayer should be more suitable.

Comment: I actually need the ability to play sounds simultaneously while being able to stop all playing sounds at certain times so using blank sound wouldn't really work in this case.

Comment: @Chase Have you already solved this problem? I'm crazy with this and can't find any solution. I just want to play a sound.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am and always was able to play the sound. The error reported was just some logcat messaging that made me curious. I have pinpointed the native calls where the message is logged, but have not found a solution that stops the messaging.